# From Ethereum Wallet testnet mode I got some ETH in main account. Is it possible use them?

Tags: wallets, wallet-transfer

Im new in this practise. I installed Ethereum Wallet for mac and immediately gone to testnet mode and started mining. After many hours on main account still in testnet mode i got some ETH. Then I created always in Testnet mode an other account and I transferred to it for test 0.5 Eth. System after procedure password confirmed sent to if successfully. So now 2 accounts in testnet mode and on top right total displayed and in accounts one part in main account and 0.5 Eth in the 2ns one. So I thought it worked ok and I created wallet contract scuccesfully with positive transaction of 0.5 Eth to it too.

 In latest transactions list there are these listed with date time and specification Transfer between accounts with, on the right, the total out with arrow direction right and colored in red. Then I thought it work ok and I did a trial to send ETH 0,05 to exchangers. I did process as usual (still in testnet mode) and sent ... From the Total balance at top right, was deducted the amount but exchanger never received the 0.5 ETH. Is there someone whom can explain me:

- 1) where gone the 0.5 I sent;
- 2) what is wrong in procedure I used;
- 3) what I have to do for do real transfer outside my accounts
- 4) what is correct setup I have to do before send outside ETH

Thanks

Comment: This question is a bit confused... All of this is inside the testnet no?

Comment: The transfer was correct, but exchanges will not accept coins from testnet, they have no value. You should be able to confirm the transaction was from ropsten.etherscan.io